# Unexpected Arrow Function Functionality in jQuery Click Event

Tags: jquery

I was playing around with the concept of using arrow functions to  execute small parts of code and then I started getting functionality that perplexed me.

When you compare the following with it's functional counterpart (listed bellow):

### Arrow Function: Removes one then the other (When clicking on #subtest)

```js
$("#test").click((e) => $(e.target).remove());
$("#subtest").click((e) => true);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test">test
 <div id="subtest">test2</div>
</div>
```

### Function Counterpart: removes both

```js
$("#test").click(function (e) {
  $(this).remove()
});
$("#subtest").click(function () {
  return true;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test">test
 <div id="subtest">test2</div>
</div>
```

I am certain this has something to do with what `e.target` is referencing because if I use `e.currentTarget` is seems to work.

### e.currentTarget version

```js
$("#test").click((e) => $(e.currentTarget).remove());
$("#subtest").click((e) => true);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test">test
 <div id="subtest">test2</div>
</div>
```

I haven't gotten a real satisfying answer via *Google* for this functionality, some help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`target` will not be the element of the selector if there are child elements and those children are acted upon

In your case you have a child that would actually be the target. This is easy to verify by `console.log(e.target)`

Conversely `currentTarget` will be the same as the selector element and is not necessarily the same as `target`. In a non arrow function handler, `currentTarget` is same as `this`

Comment: Thanks for this. I just ran across this issue today and reverted to ES5 function instead of arrow in my jQuery event handler as I was  getting unreliable results with `event.target`, now I know why. Guess I should have been using `currentTarget`